# Active Directory implementation in new app

Tags: java, spring, active-directory

I looked online no definite clarity. And whats the difference between AD and LDAP?

Comment: I never heared about OSSA before , but i explained for you the difference between AD and LDAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active Directory is a technology made by Microsoft , used by servers like *Windows Server* , to stock and edit the different objects ( *like users , computers .. etc* ) on the network , it gives the services of managing the different tasks of your network ( *like identification and authentication , updates , making strategies .. etc* )

LDAP is a protocol which uses TCP/IP , his role is to query and modify directory services , the directory of the server that contains the different objects i said above , it is the one who structure the objects inside the server ( *like a tree* )

**However Active Directory uses the protocol LDAP for many tasks such as authentication**